# How to optimize this specific python code for a very large DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, sequence

I start with a large list of all Bitcoin prices. I import it into a Dataframe.

df.head()

```
                     BTC-USDT_close
open_time
2021-11-05 22:28:00    61151.781250
2021-11-05 22:27:00    61199.011719
2021-11-05 22:26:00    61201.398438
2021-11-05 22:25:00    61237.828125
2021-11-05 22:24:00    61195.578125
...
221651 rows total.
```

What I need is the following:

For **each row** in this dataframe

1. take next 60 values
2. take next 60 in every 5 values
3. take next 60 in every 15 values
4. take next 60 in every 60 values
5. take next 60 in every 360 values
6. take next 60 in every 5760 values
7. add this new table of 60 rows as an array to a list

So in the end I want to have a lot of these:

small_df.head(6)

```
    BTC-USDT_1m   BTC-USDT_5m  BTC-USDT_15m   BTC-USDT_1h   BTC-USDT_6h   BTC-USDT_4d
0  61199.011719  61199.011719  61199.011719  61199.011719  61199.011719  61199.011719
1  61201.398438  61241.390625  61159.578125  61079.800781  60922.968750  60968.320312
2  61237.828125  61309.000000  61063.628906  60845.710938  61682.960938  60717.500000
3  61195.578125  61159.578125  61100.000000  61060.000000  62191.000000  60939.210938
4  61221.179688  61165.371094  61079.800781  61220.011719  61282.000000  65934.328125
5  61241.390625  61047.488281  61175.238281  60812.210938  61190.300781  60599.000000
...
60 rows total
```

(Basically these are the sequences of 60 previous values in different time frames)

So the code is as follows:

```
seq_list = []
for i in range(len(df) // 2):
  r = i+1
  small_df = pd.DataFrame()
  small_df['BTC-USDT_1m'] = df['BTC-USDT_close'][r:r+seq_len:1].reset_index(drop=True)
  small_df['BTC-USDT_5m'] = df['BTC-USDT_close'][r:(r+seq_len)*5:5].dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
  small_df['BTC-USDT_15m'] = df['BTC-USDT_close'][r:(r+seq_len)*15:15].dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
  small_df['BTC-USDT_1h'] = df['BTC-USDT_close'][r:(r+seq_len)*60:60].dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
  small_df['BTC-USDT_6h'] = df['BTC-USDT_close'][r:(r+seq_len)*360:360].dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
  small_df['BTC-USDT_4d'] = df['BTC-USDT_close'][r:(r+seq_len)*5760:5760].dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
  seq_list.append([small_df, df['target'][r]])
```

As you can imagine, it's very slow, it can do about 1500 sequences per minute, so the whole process is going to take 12 hours.

Could you please show me a way to speed things up?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't do this by indexing as this creates larges indexes and is inefficient. Instead, you would use `.rolling()` to create rolling windows.

You can see in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html), that rolling also supports rolling windows over timestamps. See this copy for the result:

```
>>> df_time.rolling('2s').sum()
                   B
2013-01-01 09:00:00  0.0
2013-01-01 09:00:02  1.0
2013-01-01 09:00:03  3.0
2013-01-01 09:00:05  NaN
2013-01-01 09:00:06  4.0
```

In your case, you could do the following

```
small_df['BTC-USDT_1m'] = df['BTC-USDT_close'].rolling("1m").mean().reset_index(drop=True)
```

The first argument is always the size of the window, i.e. the number of samples to take from `df`. This can be an integer for exact number of smaples or a timestamp, to march through the table based on a fixed timeframe.

In this case it would compute the mean price based on a moving window of 1 minute.

This would be way more accurate then your index-based solution, since there you do not take into account the distance between the timestamps and also you are actually just taking single values, which means you are highly dependent on local fluctuations. A mean over a given window size supplies you with the average change in price over that timespan.

However, if you want just the single price at a given size, then you simply use a small window, like

```
small_df['BTC-USDT_1m'] = df['BTC-USDT_close'].rolling(1, step=60).reset_index(drop=True)
```

The `step` argument here makes the moving window not consider every single element but rather move `60` samples each time a value is taken.

Any solution like yours or the latter with step, of course, produces a number of new samples different from the original one, thus you would have to think if you want to drop NaN values, fill in gaps, use expand, ...